# Force alt attribute on post-thumbnail wordpress

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

i want to force the attribute "alt" on thumbnail when admin add new thumbnail on wordpress.

if there is javascript hook on saving thumbnail validator on the input "title" that's well be great!

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Found this, place it in your functions.php file in your theme directory

```
function add_alt_tags($content)
{
    global $post;
    preg_match_all('/<img (.*?)\/>/', $content, $images);
    if(!is_null($images))
    {
            foreach($images[1] as $index => $value)
            {
                    if(!preg_match('/alt=/', $value))
                    {
                            $new_img = str_replace('<img', '<img alt="'.$post->post_title.'"', $images[0][$index]);
                            $content = str_replace($images[0][$index], $new_img, $content);
                    }
            }
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_alt_tags', 99999);
```

Find more here http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-missing-alt-tags-to-wordpress-images

This is going on my snippet site. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

By default, the image returned does not have a title or alt attribute. (Since WordPress 4.7, the alt attribute is no longer added automatically. It will only have an alt attribute if you specifically entered "Alt text" while uploading the image, or if you go back to the Media library and enter "Alt text" for the image).

Currently website(s) traffic from Google search is considerably higher if your images all have (title attribute tags), as well as (alt tags). So, I add the title and alt attributes to post thumbnails with the following function which goes in your theme "functions.php" file. The value for the title and alt attributes will be taken from the title of the image, which is the title of the attachment (not the actual post title).

```
function eln_add_img_title( $attr, $attachment = null ) {

$img_title = trim( strip_tags( $attachment->post_title ) );

$attr['title'] = $img_title;
$attr['alt'] = $img_title;

return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes','eln_add_img_title', 10, 2
);
```

> If you don't want the image attributes taken from default image name
>   you can change the code so the image attributes taken from
>   "post_title" as follow:

```
// Force adding missing image alt & title for WordPress.
function eln_add_img_title( $attr, $attachment = null ) {

$img_title = trim( strip_tags( $attachment->post_title ) );

$attr['title'] = the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' );
$attr['alt'] = the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' );

return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes','isa_add_img_title', 10, 2     );
```

Hope this help you and save your time, Have a nice day :)